Laminas authentication using lmcuser package with custom db adaper
My Zendframework2 application is working fine in the php 7.4 and i have to update it to support php 8.1 and for that i am migrating zf2 to laminas.
It was zfcuser implemented in the ZF2. Currently i am replacing zfcuser with lmcuser package in laminas and in the custom authentication getting error in this line
$result = $adapter->prepareForAuthentication($this->getRequest());  

and after commenting this line getting authentication code 0 means it is failing.
my authentication method is this
public function authenticateAction() {
        if ($this->lmcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity()) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute($this->getOptions()->getLoginRedirectRoute());
        }
        $adapter = $this->lmcUserAuthentication()->getAuthAdapter();
        
        $redirect = $this->params()->fromPost('redirect', $this->params()->fromQuery('redirect', false));
        
            $result = $adapter->prepareForAuthentication($this->getRequest());
        
        // Return early if an adapter returned a response
        if ($result instanceof Response) {
            return $result;
        }

        $auth = $this->lmcUserAuthentication()->getAuthService()->authenticate($adapter);
        

i checked adapter, request data and authservice using var_dump, all are having data.
getting error
Call to a member function get() on null in Authentication/Adapter/Db.php
on
$this->setOptions($this->getServiceManager()->get('lmcuser_module_options')); 

line
error is in
$this->getServiceManager()->get('lmcuser_module_options') c

ode
Db.php file look like the below
public function preprocessCredential($credential) {
        $processor = $this->getCredentialPreprocessor();
        if (is_callable($processor)) {
            return $processor($credential);
        }
        return $credential;
    }

    /**
     * getMapper
     *
     * @return UserMapperInterface
     */
    public function getMapper() {
        if (null === $this->mapper) {
            $this->mapper = $this->getServiceManager()->get('lmcuser_user_mapper');
        }

        return $this->mapper;
    }

    /**
     * setMapper
     *
     * @param UserMapperInterface $mapper
     * @return Db
     */
    public function setMapper(UserInterface $mapper) {
        $this->mapper = $mapper;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get credentialPreprocessor.
     *
     * @return \callable
     */
    public function getCredentialPreprocessor() {
        return $this->credentialPreprocessor;
    }

    /**
     * Set credentialPreprocessor.
     *
     * @param $credentialPreprocessor the value to be set
     */
    public function setCredentialPreprocessor($credentialPreprocessor) {
        $this->credentialPreprocessor = $credentialPreprocessor;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve service manager instance
     *
     * @return ServiceManager
     */
    public function getServiceManager() {
        return $this->serviceManager;
    }

    /**
     * Set service manager instance
     *
     * @param ServiceManager $locator
     * @return void
     */
    public function setServiceManager(ContainerInterface $serviceManager)
    {
        $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param AuthenticationOptionsInterface $options
     */
    public function setOptions(AuthenticationOptionsInterface $options) {
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    /**
     * @return AuthenticationOptionsInterface
     */
    public function getOptions() {
        if ($this->options === null) {
        
            $this->setOptions($this->getServiceManager()->get('lmcuser_module_options'));
        }
        return $this->options;
    }

lmcuser_module_option configured in the module.config.php file like this
'service_manager' => [
            'factories' => [
                'Router' => 'Laminas\Router\Http\HttpRouterFactory',
                'ViewHelperManager' => 'Laminas\View\HelperPluginManagerFactory',
                'LmcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChain' => 'LmcUser\Factory\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChainFactory',
                // 'LmcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChain' => LmcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChainServiceFactory::class,
                'LmcUser\Authentication\Adapter\Chain' => 'LmcUser\Factory\Authentication\Adapter\ChainFactory',
                'LmcUser\Service\User' => 'LmcUser\Factory\UserFactory',
                \LmcUser\Authentication\AuthenticationService::class => function($container) {
                    return new \LmcUser\Authentication\AuthenticationService(
                        $container->get('lmcuser_auth_adapter_chain'),
                        $container->get('lmcuser_auth_storage')
                    );
                },
                'lmcuser_module_options' => \LmcUser\Factory\ModuleOptionsFactory::class,
                'lmcuser_auth_adapter_chain' => function($container) {
                    return new \LmcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChain(); // Adjust according to your setup
                },
                'lmcuser_auth_storage' => function($container) {
                    return new \Laminas\Authentication\Storage\Session(); // Adjust according to your setup
                },
                LmcUser\Options\UserControllerOptionsInterface::class => \LmcUser\Factory\Options\UserControllerOptionsFactory::class,
                'Backend\Authentication\Adapter\Db' => function (ContainerInterface $container) {
                    $dbAdapter = new \Backend\Authentication\Adapter\Db();
                    $dbAdapter->setServiceManager($container);
                    return $dbAdapter;
                },
            
            ],
            'aliases' => [
                'lmcuser_auth_service' => \LmcUser\Authentication\AuthenticationService::class,
                UserControllerOptionsInterface::class => ModuleOptions::class,
            ],
        ],
    ),


Can anybody help me to get resolved this issue?
